# Android get Image of Main Relativelayout from xml layout?

Tags: android

I have xml file and that create view and i pass that screen shot in next activity.and also there are image with  main layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/imageSelected"
        android:src="@drawable/icon" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="79dp"></ImageView>

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/relativelayoutfinal" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayoutbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <include layout="@layout/bottombutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:background="@drawable/b_brightness_contrast"
        android:id="@+id/btnbrightcont" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dip" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_marginRight="103dp"></Button>
    <Button android:background="@drawable/b_adjust_and_scale"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/btnadjustscale"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnbrightcont" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnbrightcont"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>

    <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:progress="50"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dip" android:layout_marginRight="30dip"
        android:layout_width="160dip" android:id="@+id/sbbrightness"
        android:visibility="gone" android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"></SeekBar>
    <SeekBar android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:progress="50"
        android:visibility="gone" android:layout_width="160dip" android:id="@+id/sbcontrast"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sbbrightness" android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/sbbrightness"></SeekBar>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and just send image as drawable or bitmap to next activity...Its Possible??

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As far as I understand, that you want screen shot of your relativelayout xml :

For this you can use:

```
 View v = yourrelativelayout.getRootView();
             v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
             Bitmap bitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
             BitmapDrawable drawable=new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
```

You can use this BitmapDrawable as Drawable and can pass to the next activity.

Hope it helps.

Comment: but when i pass bitmapdrawable to other activity can set fill parent and view are not same as this view///

Comment: that means when you are using this bitmapdrawable , you can use fillparent and setbackground for the layout so it comes full screen..is that u asked?

Comment: ya bitmapdrawable cant set in fullscreen in next activity?