# How to take a screenshot of the CameraPreview in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I need quick access to the CameraPreview data for my new flutter app.
If I take a picture with `controller.takePicture(filePath)` it takes a few seconds for the file to save to the disk, so that I can access it.
I don't need a high quality image, so getting the same resolution as the phone screen display resolution would be fine. I have tried [this method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html), but it only captures the overlays and widgets that I drew myself, not the Camera preview data.
Here is a minimum working example of the problem when using [this method](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/rendering/RenderRepaintBoundary/toImage.html):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CWBLjCwH5c0

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

List<CameraDescription> cameras;

Future<Null> main() async {
  debugPaintSizeEnabled = false;
  debugPaintLayerBordersEnabled = false;
  try {
    cameras = await availableCameras();
  } on CameraException catch (e) {
    logError(e.code, e.description);
  }

  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    home: new MyApp(),
  ));
}

void logError(String code, String message) =>
    print('Error: $code\nError Message: $message');

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => new _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  static GlobalKey previewContainer = new GlobalKey();
  CameraController controller;
  ui.Image image;
  Offset blueSquareOffset = new Offset(10.0, 10.0);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    controller = new CameraController(cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.low);
    controller.initialize().then((_) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      }
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _getScreenShotImage() async {
    _capturePng();
    image = await _capturePng();
    debugPrint("im height: ${image.height}, im width: ${image.width}");
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<ui.Image> _capturePng() async {
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary =
        previewContainer.currentContext.findRenderObject();
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage();
    return image;
  }

  /// Display the preview from the camera (or a message if the preview is not available).
  Widget _cameraPreviewWidget() {
    if (controller == null || !controller.value.isInitialized) {
      return const Text('Camera is initialising...');
    } else {
      return Center(
        child: new AspectRatio(
            aspectRatio: controller.value.aspectRatio,
            child: RepaintBoundary(
              //key: previewContainer,
              child: new GestureDetector(
                child: new CameraPreview(controller),
              ),
            )),
      );
    }
  }

  void _moveBlueSquare(DragUpdateDetails details) {
    setState(() {
      _getScreenShotImage();
      blueSquareOffset = blueSquareOffset + details.delta;
    });
  }

  Widget _blueSquare() {
    return new Positioned(
        top: blueSquareOffset.dy,
        left: blueSquareOffset.dx,
        width: 50.0,
        height: 50.0,
        child: new GestureDetector(
            onPanUpdate: _moveBlueSquare,
            child: new Container(
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 10, 10, 255),
            )));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text('Render Boundry Screenshot Error Example'),
        ),
        body: RepaintBoundary(
            key: previewContainer,
            child: new Container(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                margin: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                child: new RepaintBoundary(
                    //key: previewContainer,
                    child: new Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  overflow: Overflow.clip,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    new Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        new Expanded(
                            child: new Stack(children: <Widget>[
                          new RepaintBoundary(
                            child: new Container(child: _cameraPreviewWidget()),
                          ),
                          _blueSquare(),
                        ])),
                        new Expanded(
                          child: new Container(
                              //color: Color.fromARGB(50, 50, 50, 50),
                              child: new CustomPaint(
                            painter: new RectanglePainter(image),
                          )),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ],
                )))));
  }
}

class RectanglePainter extends CustomPainter {
  RectanglePainter(this.image);

  ui.Image image;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    if (image == null) {
      canvas.drawRect(
          new Rect.fromLTRB(100.0, 50.0, 300.0, 200.0),
          new Paint()
            ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 50, 50, 255)
            ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke
            ..strokeWidth = 6.0);
    } else {
      canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(0.0, 0.0), new Paint());
    }
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(RectanglePainter old) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm currently exploring the Flutter screenshot package: https://pub.dev/packages/screenshot which might do the job. I'll update on the progress.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: July 2020**

At the moment, the best way to get a screenshot of the CameraPreview on Flutter, is to use the [native_screenshot](https://pub.dev/packages/native_screenshot) package.

You can simply use,

```
Future<void> getScreenshot() async{
    String path = await NativeScreenshot.takeScreenshot();
    print(path);
  }
```

to save the screenshot. Please refer to package page for additional permissions and settings. Performance-wise, it seems to be a bit slow (500ms-1s on my 2018 Xiaomi A1). I am currently looking at ways to improve the screen capture speed.

Comment: it does not capture camera preview, tested it.
It capture all the stuff on screen and save it in gallery but camera preview is not there instead black screen.

Comment: since it saves an image in the gallery (with black screen), it could be that you are not handling the camera frame correctly maybe?

Comment: Same code works on IOS but not on Android.
You might wanna check it again.
Especially on Android 11

Comment: this used to work but I cannot get it to work on android 13 ;-/ path always null, any other way?

Answer (score 0):

So, it can be done using image stream:

```
late CameraController _controller;
CameraImage? _image;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _controller = CameraController(MyApp.cameras[0], ResolutionPreset.high);
  _controller.initialize().then((_) {
    if (!mounted) return;

    _controller.startImageStream((image) {
      _image = image;
      setState(() { });
    });
  });
}
```

You can still use `CameraPreview`, but when you need to take a photo, just use the last `CameraImage` value.

`CameraImage` itself can’t be displayed, you have to convert it to `Uint8List` first. [Here](https://gist.github.com/Alby-o/fe87e35bc21d534c8220aed7df028e03?permalink_comment_id=4555000#gistcomment-4555000) I've found this code (you'll need to install https://pub.dev/packages/image):

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:image/image.dart' as imglib;

/// ImageUtils
class ImageUtils {
  ///
  /// Converts a [CameraImage] to [image_lib.Image] in RGB format
  ///
  static imglib.Image convertCameraImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
    if (cameraImage.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.yuv420) {
      return convertYUV420ToImage(cameraImage);
    } else if (cameraImage.format.group == ImageFormatGroup.bgra8888) {
      return convertBGRA8888ToImage(cameraImage);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Undefined image type.');
    }
  }

  ///
  /// Converts a [CameraImage] in BGRA888 format to [image_lib.Image] in RGB format
  ///
  static imglib.Image convertBGRA8888ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
    return imglib.Image.fromBytes(
      width: cameraImage.planes[0].width!,
      height: cameraImage.planes[0].height!,
      bytes: cameraImage.planes[0].bytes.buffer,
      order: imglib.ChannelOrder.bgra,
    );
  }

  ///
  /// Converts a [CameraImage] in YUV420 format to [image_lib.Image] in RGB format
  ///
  static imglib.Image convertYUV420ToImage(CameraImage cameraImage) {
    final imageWidth = cameraImage.width;
    final imageHeight = cameraImage.height;

    final yBuffer = cameraImage.planes[0].bytes;
    final uBuffer = cameraImage.planes[1].bytes;
    final vBuffer = cameraImage.planes[2].bytes;

    final int yRowStride = cameraImage.planes[0].bytesPerRow;
    final int yPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[0].bytesPerPixel!;

    final int uvRowStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerRow;
    final int uvPixelStride = cameraImage.planes[1].bytesPerPixel!;

    final image = imglib.Image(width: imageWidth, height: imageHeight);

    for (int h = 0; h < imageHeight; h++) {
      int uvh = (h / 2).floor();

      for (int w = 0; w < imageWidth; w++) {
        int uvw = (w / 2).floor();

        final yIndex = (h * yRowStride) + (w * yPixelStride);

        // Y plane should have positive values belonging to [0...255]
        final int y = yBuffer[yIndex];

        // U/V Values are subsampled i.e. each pixel in U/V chanel in a
        // YUV_420 image act as chroma value for 4 neighbouring pixels
        final int uvIndex = (uvh * uvRowStride) + (uvw * uvPixelStride);

        // U/V values ideally fall under [-0.5, 0.5] range. To fit them into
        // [0, 255] range they are scaled up and centered to 128.
        // Operation below brings U/V values to [-128, 127].
        final int u = uBuffer[uvIndex];
        final int v = vBuffer[uvIndex];

        // Compute RGB values per formula above.
        int r = (y + v * 1436 / 1024 - 179).round();
        int g = (y - u * 46549 / 131072 + 44 - v * 93604 / 131072 + 91).round();
        int b = (y + u * 1814 / 1024 - 227).round();

        r = r.clamp(0, 255);
        g = g.clamp(0, 255);
        b = b.clamp(0, 255);

        image.setPixelRgb(w, h, r, g, b);
      }
    }

    return image;
  }
}
```

Then you can convert `Image` to `Uint8List` like this:

```
imglib.Image image = ImageUtils.convertCameraImage(_image);

image = imglib.copyRotate(image, angle: 90); // In my case I also needed rotation

Uint8List result = imglib.encodeJpg(image);
```

The `result` can be then used as `Image.memory(result)`.

Now you have your photo instantly. BTW, in this case you can just pause preview to show the result, no need to display it as an `Image` widget, so taking photo will be very smooth and fast for the users.

Answer (score -2):

There is a way to take snapshot from layouts. try this:

[Android get Image of Main Relativelayout from xml layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982464/android-get-image-of-main-relativelayout-from-xml-layout)

I hope this helps to you.

Comment: thats not flutter, but cheers.